# I have System.Drawing (v2.0) added but compiler asks for it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, .net-2.0, system.drawing

I have a project (for SmartDevice) where I need to add a reference to System.Drawing (v2.0) what I have done but the compiler keeps asking for it.

Anyone has some idea how to solve this ?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Which version of the framework does your project reference?

Comment: 2.0, but I have also tries starting the project from scratch for 3.5. I think though, I have found the answer (not really god news for me) [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162515/cant-find-referenced-assembly-when-compiling-for-windows-mobile)

Comment: Please be sure to add a descriptive answer to your question describing what you've found so future readers can learn from your experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that Tesseract OCR will not currently run in Windows Mobile. Various people have tried and suggested solutions such as using the GRAPHICS_DISABLED or EMBEDDED compiler defines, but no one has reported this to be working yet.

Due to the computational complexity of OCR and the limited resources available in the WinMo platform, there are not many solutions available, but you could try:

1) Getting the tesseract source and applying the suggested compiled directives

2) [TextRact](http://www.xda-developers.com/android/textract-ocr-for-android-and-windows-mobile/) for android and winmo.

3) [The ABBYY Mobile OCR Engine](http://www.abbyy.com/mobileocr/).

Answer (score 1):

CompactFramework and regular desktop framework components are different. Something, somewhere, in your project is using the desktop version of System.Drawing... either your reference is to the wrong version or you're using a component that references the desktop version.